# GTK3: Widget mouse events pass-through

Tags: gtk3

I have a custom GtkDrawingArea-based widget inside a GtkHeaderBar which is basically a slider that receives mouse clicks and moves. Everything worked fine in GTK 3.14-something, but in 3.22 things went south: when I click and drag inside my widget, GTK thinks I'm trying to drag the window (first few pixels go to the widget, but then the window takes over).

How do I prevent mouse events from propagating to the window?

Both motion-notify-event and button-press-event return TRUE (that did the trick in 3.14, not anymore).

```
g_sinal_connect(Something->DrawingArea, "motion-notify-event", G_CALLBACK(Something_motion), Something);
g_signal_connect(Something->DrawingArea, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(Something_press), Something);
```

Comment: Are there any handler(s) installed on your drawing elements which are capturing events? Remember you have to end those handlers with FALSE to allow the events to the underlying widgets. How do you draw your custom widget?

Comment: @jcoppens, I have 3 handlers: motion-notify-event, button-press-event and button-release-event. I want to PREVENT them from propagating to the underlying widget (GtkHeaderBar, to be precise), which is why I return TRUE. It used to work, but stopped working in the newer GTK versions. I draw using Cairo in the "draw" callback.

Answer (score 1):

Answering as an answer, as I can't input code into the 'comments'.

I suspect you have to enable the `EventMask` corresponding to the `DrawingArea`. This is somewhat different from other widgets, I guess.

Below is a small demo program in `Python3` (this basically connects directly to the Gtk3.2x libraries, so should be similar to what you want to do in C.

Changing the return `True` to `False` in `area_button_press()` will make it transparent to the `button_press_event`, as expected. Commenting the line with `...add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)` is needed in the code to make the `button-press-event` to be recognized at all:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_headerbar_events.py
#
#  Copyright 2017 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
#


from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_default_size(200, -1)

        hdrbar = Gtk.HeaderBar(title = "Header bar")
        hdrbar.connect("button-press-event", self.hdrbar_button_press)

        drawing_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        drawing_area.set_size_request(30, 30)
        drawing_area.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
        drawing_area.connect("button-press-event", self.area_button_press)

        frame = Gtk.Frame()
        frame.add(drawing_area)

        hdrbar.pack_start(frame)

        self.add(hdrbar)
        self.show_all()

    def area_button_press(self, btn, event):
        print("Button pressed on Drawing Area")
        return True

    def hdrbar_button_press(self, btn, event):
        print("Button pressed on Header Bar")
        return False


    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

**EDIT**: If you use `set_titlebar()`, the events seem to go directly to the windowmanager (which would probably be what you want normally), instead of the underlying window. If you want to control (block) the movement of the window you could

- Not use `set_titlebar()` and use `set_decorations(False)`, which will hide the window's titlebar and show your headerbar at the top. Then the events will be controllable. Use a VBox to store your headerbar and the content of the rest of the window.
- Of course. this way you will have to implement window dragging yourself (which is not too complicated). If needed, have a look at the [GUI frontend I made for the Wcalc calculator](http://jcoppens.com/soft/gwcalc/index.en.php) (years ago - you may need to tweak the Gtk calls),

Comment: I noticed that removing GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK does prevent window dragging. Of course it also leaves the drawing area with no event. Your python sample is a bit different from my case: replace self.add(hdrbar) with self.set_titlebar(hdrbar), then add POINTER_MOTION_MASK to witness the issue.

Comment: I see... I've added an edit to the answer above. Maybe that's a solution to your problem?

Comment: I just came here to say that I decided to throw away GTK3 completely. There were other issues and it seems to me the platform cannot be trusted. I'd rather not make my projects depend on it. Thanks anyway.